# Idiomatic Node error handling

Tags: node.js, error-handling, callback, idioms

So I am doing a nodejs tutorial and it asks me to use modules to filter all the files in a directory. And I'm supposed to use the idiomatic approach to handle errors. Below is my modules.js and my main program.js, however, the program said that

```
Your additional module file [module.js] does not appear to pass back an
error received from fs.readdir(). Use the following idiomatic Node.js
pattern inside your callback to fs.readdir():
if (err) return
callback(err)
```

but I did handle the error on the first line using `if (err)return callback(err);`

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong or what best practice I'm not following? Thanks

```
module.exports = function filterList(dirName, extName, callback) {

fs.readdir(dirName, function callback(err, list) {

    if (err)
        return callback(err);
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (path.extname(list[i]) == '.' + extName) {
            callback(null, list[i]);
        }
    };
});
}
```

my program.js is as follows

```
var myMod = require('./module');
function printOut(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    };
    console.log(result);
}

myMod(process.argv[2], process.argv[3], printOut);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two functions named `callback` here which is causing unexpected behavior.

Your main exported function takes an argument name `callback`. Then inside that you define another function named `callback':

```
function filterList(dirName, extName, callback){ // <-- callback as arg
    fs.readdir(dirName, function callback(err, list) { // <-- callback defined again
        if (err)
          return callback(err);  // <-- which function is this calling?
  /* etc. */
}
```

When you finally `return callback(err)` you are calling the wrong function. You want to call the first one -- the one passed into `filterList()`, but the second one is in scope.

You could instead pass an anonymous function to `fs.readdir` since you never need to call it:

```
 fs.readdir(dirName, function(err, list) {
    if (err)
      return callback(err);  // <-- now there's only one call back
```

Now it's clear that you are calling the correct callback and it's more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

You're shadowing your `callback` by naming the function the same as the argument. Try this:

```
module.exports = function filterList(dirName, extName, callback) {
  fs.readdir(dirName, function cb(err, list) {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (path.extname(list[i]) == '.' + extName) {
        callback(null, list[i]);
      }
    };
  });
}
```

Notice the rename of the second paramerter to `fs.readdir` is now named `cb`, you don't actually need to name it, but it does help for stack traces and logging.

One other thing, you are going to have an issue calling `callback` inside a loop. There are ways to break out of it and also ways to avoid having it in the loop.